# RQ-Jobs Failing for No reason

Tags: python, queue, jobs, worker, rq

This is info for simple print function.
Jobs with any function is failing without no distinct reason.

Status: failed

Job: <Job fdee8b46-3a9a-4014-b82f-370616bf3325: ams.ams(<Request 'http://172.17.0.2:5000/task/upload/4' [POST]>, '4')>

```
Info: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rq/worker.py", line 970, in perform_job
    self.prepare_job_execution(job, heartbeat_ttl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rq/worker.py", line 867, in prepare_job_execution
    self.procline(msg.format(job.func_name, job.origin, time.time()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rq/job.py", line 247, in func_name
    self._deserialize_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rq/job.py", line 215, in _deserialize_data
    self._func_name, self._instance, self._args, self._kwargs = self.serializer.loads(self.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 305, in _get_current_object
    if not hasattr(self.__local, "__release_local__"):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Using Py2.7 is not a really great option

Answer (score 0):

For some reason these errors are due to using python3.